# Call to undefined method Illuminate\Foundation\Application::registerCoreContainerAliases()

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, composer-php

I have just updated laravel using composer update.

My composer.json looks like this:

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "require": {
        "laravel/framework": "4.1.*",
        "way/generators": "dev-master",
        "twitter/bootstrap": "dev-master",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "3.7.*",
        "goodby/csv": "1.1.0",
        "iron-io/iron_mq": "1.4.8",
        "bugsnag/bugsnag-laravel": "1.*"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "app/commands",
            "app/controllers",
            "app/models",
            "app/library",
            "app/database/migrations",
            "app/database/seeds",
            "app/tests/TestCase.php"
        ]
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "pre-update-cmd": [
            "php artisan clear-compiled"
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "php artisan key:generate"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist"
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "require-dev": {
        "itsgoingd/clockwork": "dev-master"
    }
}
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
 Error Output: PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method Illuminate\Foundation\Application::registerCoreContainerAliases() in /var/www/web/beequick-test/htdocs/laravel/vendor/laravel/fram 
 ework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/start.php on line 106
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just had to remove the file in bootstrap/compiled.php as mentioned here : http://www.neontsunami.com/post/laravel-4-php-fatal-error-call-to-undefined-method-illuminate-foundation-application-registercorecontaineraliases%28%29

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Laravel 5, you will delete the vendor/compiled.php file